# How do i access the properties of a many-to-many with Membership in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

How can i set only mine membership, instead of all in for-loop ?

template.html:

```
         {% for g in gr %}

           <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="jumbo2">
              <form method="POST" class="post-form"> {% csrf_token %}
                <p id="name"><b>Groups name:</b> {{g.name}}</p><br>

                {% for membership in g.membership_set.all %}

                      <p><b>Member:</b> {{ membership.person }} - {{ membership.role }}</p>                            

                {% endfor %}






                <br>
                <span class="desc2">Groups description:</span>
                <p id="desc">{{g.description}}</p><br>



                {% for membership in g.membership_set.all %}

                      {% if membership.leader == False %}
                        <button style="float: right" type="submit" name = "leave"  value = "{{g.name}}" class="save btn btn-default">Leave</button>
                      {% elif membership.leader == True %}
                        <button style="float: right" type="submit" name = "delete"  value = "{{g.name}}" class="save btn btn-default">Delete</button>
                      {% endif %}

                 {% endfor %}
              </form>
              <br><br>
              <p></p>



                </div>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
```

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=350)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My buttons are displeyed as many as i have users in some group.
I want to display only 1 button, and i need to precise ForLoop only for my membership in this group. How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "My Membership"? It's completely unclear. Can you also post your models.

Comment: I mean that, the loop {% for membership in g.membership_set.all %} is going through all memberships in some group. And that's why when i wanna check is my membership (my person in this group) have leader field on True or False, but this loop what i have now, is going through all members (all memberships) in this group. 

Ok, i change and add models

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this just by using standard template code. You would need to get your `Membership` object by filtering the memberships like so:

```
membership = my_person.membership_set.get(group=my_group)
```

To do this in the template, you would have to write your [own template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) that works on the `my_person` object and takes the `my_group` object as parameter. The filter could then apply the above query and return the membership object.

```
{% with membership=my_person|get_group_membership:g %}
    {% if membership.leader == False %}
        <button style="float: right" type="submit" name = "leave"  value = "{{g.name}}" class="save btn btn-default">Leave</button>
    {% elif membership.leader == True %}
        <button style="float: right" type="submit" name = "delete"  value = "{{g.name}}" class="save btn btn-default">Delete</button>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```